# Resolve duplicates after Pandas merge

Tags: python, pandas, merge, duplicates

I have two Pandas Dataframes, named table_A and table_B:

**table_A**

| ID | COST | DATE | MONTH |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| CLSLT88150 | 655.118 | 2019-12-30 | 1 |
| CLSLT88150 | 652.758 | 2019-12-30 | 1 |

**table_B**

| ID | NUMBER | ORDER | DEVICE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| CLSLT88150 | 4.45882e+07 | WO-SLT-GLI-REC-0009-5067 | Apple iPhone XR |
| CLSLT88150 | 4.45882e+07 | WO-SLT-GLI-REC-0009-5786 | Apple iPhone XR |

I want to *merge* these two tables on column **ID** to obtain a result similar to this table:

**table_merge**

| ID | COST | DATE | MONTH | ORDER | NUMBER | DEVICE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| CLSLT88150 | 655.118 | 2019-12-30 | 1 | WO-SLT-GLI-REC-0009-5067 | 4.45882e+07 | Apple iPhone XR |
| CLSLT88150 | 652.758 | 2019-12-30 | 1 | WO-SLT-GLI-REC-0009-5786 | 4.45882e+07 | Apple iPhone XR |

Each **ID** can have multiple **ORDER**. Each **ORDER** can only appear once and has a unique **COST** associated. It is indifferent which **COST** is associated with which **ORDER**, so this table could also be an acceptable result:

| ID | COST | DATE | MONTH | ORDER | NUMBER | DEVICE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| CLSLT88150 | 652.758 | 2019-12-30 | 1 | WO-SLT-GLI-REC-0009-5067 | 4.45882e+07 | Apple iPhone XR |
| CLSLT88150 | 655.118 | 2019-12-30 | 1 | WO-SLT-GLI-REC-0009-5786 | 4.45882e+07 | Apple iPhone XR |

I have used the following script to *merge* **table_A** with **table_B**:

```
table_merge = table_A.merge(table_B)
```

Obtaining this undesired result:

| ID | COST | DATE | MONTH | ORDER | NUMBER | DEVICE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| CLSLT88150 | 655.118 | 2019-12-30 | 1 | WO-SLT-GLI-REC-0009-5067 | 4.45882e+07 | Apple iPhone XR |
| CLSLT88150 | 655.118 | 2019-12-30 | 1 | WO-SLT-GLI-REC-0009-5786 | 4.45882e+07 | Apple iPhone XR |
| CLSLT88150 | 652.758 | 2019-12-30 | 1 | WO-SLT-GLI-REC-0009-5067 | 4.45882e+07 | Apple iPhone XR |
| CLSLT88150 | 652.758 | 2019-12-30 | 1 | WO-SLT-GLI-REC-0009-5786 | 4.45882e+07 | Apple iPhone XR |

I tried and failed to remove the undesired rows with this script:

```
table_merge = table_merge.drop_duplicates(subset=['ORDER','ID'])
```

After dropping duplicates **table_merge** looks like this:

| ID | COST | DATE | MONTH | ORDER | NUMBER | DEVICE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| CLSLT88150 | 655.118 | 2019-12-30 | 1 | WO-SLT-GLI-REC-0009-5067 | 4.45882e+07 | Apple iPhone XR |
| CLSLT88150 | 655.118 | 2019-12-30 | 1 | WO-SLT-GLI-REC-0009-5786 | 4.45882e+07 | Apple iPhone XR |

As it can be appreciated the **COST** 655.118 is repeated and the other **COST** of 652.758 is missing.

How can I obtain the desired result?

Thank you.

Comment: what's the business rule to select the different cost?

Comment: @Umar.H There is no particular rule in cost selection. I think it is indifferent to this task. The only rule is that **ORDER** must be unique with a unique **COST** associated.

Comment: @Umar.H No this script does not work as **ORDER** is repeated.

Comment: @GGS after you drop duplicates, one order ends in 5067 while the other ends in 5786. Is this not the expected behavior?

Comment: again - I will have to fall back and say you need to provide more business logic, this can be done in a number of ways but not without making up some rules. Essentially your problem is that you have a `cost_table` with no order_id, you have a `device_table` with an `ORDER` but no credible way of linking it to what cost, there is no date associated with it you can join on.

Comment: @JasonCook It may be the expected behavior but not the behavior that I want. If you look closely the **COST** is repeated and the other **COST** is missing.

Comment: @Umar.H You are right but it is difficult to all share information since it is sensible. Nevertheless, I have found a hacky solution.

Comment: @GGS seems like a good solution to me :)

Answer (score 2):

All undesired repetitions appear in groups of 4 rows. By simply selecting the first and last row the duplicates issue is resolved. The code looks like this:

```
def resolve_duplicates(df):
    indexes = df.index
    return df[(df.index == indexes[0]) | (df.index == indexes[-1])]
```

Using as input:

| ID | COST | DATE | MONTH | ORDER | NUMBER | DEVICE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| CLSLT88150 | 655.118 | 2019-12-30 | 1 | WO-SLT-GLI-REC-0009-5067 | 4.45882e+07 | Apple iPhone XR |
| CLSLT88150 | 655.118 | 2019-12-30 | 1 | WO-SLT-GLI-REC-0009-5786 | 4.45882e+07 | Apple iPhone XR |
| CLSLT88150 | 652.758 | 2019-12-30 | 1 | WO-SLT-GLI-REC-0009-5067 | 4.45882e+07 | Apple iPhone XR |
| CLSLT88150 | 652.758 | 2019-12-30 | 1 | WO-SLT-GLI-REC-0009-5786 | 4.45882e+07 | Apple iPhone XR |

The output of the function is:

| ID | COST | DATE | MONTH | ORDER | NUMBER | DEVICE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| CLSLT88150 | 655.118 | 2019-12-30 | 1 | WO-SLT-GLI-REC-0009-5067 | 4.45882e+07 | Apple iPhone XR |
| CLSLT88150 | 652.758 | 2019-12-30 | 1 | WO-SLT-GLI-REC-0009-5786 | 4.45882e+07 | Apple iPhone XR |